# HTML Style tag equivalent of "font size+2"

Tags: html, css, styles, stylesheet

What is the new "style" way of temporary increasing a font size, and then returning back to the normal (without using CSS, or is CSS the better way?).

I want to insert a Hebrew word in my text, and for beginners, the Hebrew font is just too small.  I always want it bigger than the current font size, not pegged to some specific size.

Line 1 below works (the old way of doing things). 
What is the fix to line 2?

```
This is normal.  <font size="+2">bigger</font> back to norm. 
<span style='{FONT-SIZE: +2}'> and also bigger</span>.
```

Comment: FYI the "style" attribute is used to specify inline CSS.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20805668/what-is-best-replacement-for-font-size-x-in-css

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CSS is the better way to do this.

`<span style="font-size: 120%;"></span>`

Answer (score 14):

I would create a class (let's say .hebrew) and set the font-size property to 1.2em. This way whatever the font size is of the surrounding text, the text with the class of hebrew will be 20% larger.

```
.hebrew {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

Here's a quick **[demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xR7dY/)** to illustrate (colored with green to help show the difference).

And as noted in the comments, to use this in your HTML you would add the class like so:

```
<span class="hebrew"> malesuada augue imperdiet eget. Cum et magnis</span>
```

Comment: This seems like the best way to go.  Then later you can easily change your hebrew rendering all in one place, including changing fonts, etc.

Comment: PS to use this in your HTML, you would put:  `The word is <span class="hebrew">שלום</span>.`

Comment: Cool.  I'll just have to find now where the CSS is in my WordPress theme; today, just doing a quick proof-of-concept, writing a WordPress "shortcode".

Answer (score 10):

`<font size="+2">` is equivalent to `font-size: x-large;` so your second line should be

```
<span style='font-size: x-large;'> and also bigger</span>.
```

Comment: How about `<font size="+0">`. What is the equivalence? Is it `larger`?