# What is best replacement for <font size="X"> in CSS?

Tags: css, html

I am working on updating an old website which uses font tags, to use CSS.  The old HTML uses numeric font sizes (1-7) like this:

```
<font size="4">Some text</font>
```

What are the equivalent CSS sizes (in `px`, `em`, etc.) for these legacy font tag sizes?

Comment: To clarify, you're not asking how to set a font size in CSS, but asking what size font those numbers represented?

Comment: You guess my mind. I'm asking option two from your question.

Comment: This might be able to help: http://style.cleverchimp.com/font_size_intervals/altintervals.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

from W3C

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#edef-FONT

> size  = cdata [CN] Deprecated.
>
> This attribute sets the size of the font. Possible values:
>
> - An integer between 1 and 7. This sets the font to some fixed size,    whose rendering depends on the user agent. Not all user agents may
>   render all seven sizes.
> - A relative increase in font size. The value "+1" means one size    larger. The value "-3" means three sizes smaller. All sizes belong to
>   the scale of 1 to 7.

front this peice you could clearly see that equivalent to size will be `large or x-large .. etc`

explanation :

`<font size="3">` is just as if you used `font-size: medium ;`

`<font size="4">` is just as if you used `font-size: large ;`

`<font size="5">` is just as if you used `font-size: x-large ;`

`<font size="6">` is just as if you used `font-size: xx-large ;`

`<font size="7">` is just as if you used `font-size: -webkit-xxx-large;`

---

update :

i think i have got it wrong the first time it's not em's (although they work similarly). please see the update :)

Comment: What about size=1 and size=2? Don't they have an equivalent?

Answer (score 8):

**xx-small, x-small, small, medium, large, x-large, xx-large**
A set of absolute size keywords based on the user's default font size (which is medium). Similar to presentational HTML's  through  where the user's default font size is .

```
/* <absolute-size> values */
font-size: xx-small  
font-size: x-small /* <font size="1"> */
font-size: small /* <font size="2"> */
font-size: medium /* <font size="3"> */
font-size: large /* <font size="4"> */
font-size: x-large /* <font size="5"> */
font-size: xx-large /* <font size="6"> */
font-size: -webkit-xxx-large; /* <font size="7"> */
```

**Reference**

- [CSS font-size - Mozilla Development: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size)

Comment: Thanks!! This is the perfect alternative for <font size="7"> {font sizes 1 to 7} wrt latest browsers. -webkit-xxx-large will not work in IE and we can use 48px instead. Ref {http://help.dottoro.com/lcocpfmq.php}

Answer (score 2):

There is no defined mapping in approved specifications. HTML specifications do not say that what the values in `<font size=...>` mean; they are just a browser-dependent scale of sizes (and could all map to a single size). Similarly, CSS specifications do not define the meanings of `font-size` keyword values as absolute sizes *or* in HTML terms.

HTML5 CR, which is work in progress, suggests a specific [mapping](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#phrasing-content-0), except that it does not define the CSS counterpart of `xxx-large`; it just describes it as being a value that “is a non-CSS value used here to indicate a font size 50% larger than 'xx-large'”.

It is generally not useful to look for the mapping. For legacy pages, which might rely on some specific values for `font size`, just let them be. There is no point in trying to modernize them, e.g. by switching from presentational HTML to CSS. For new pages, the crucial question is what font sizes suit your needs, and for them, you had better forget `<font size>` entirely.