# CSS equivalent of <Font size="+0">

Tags: html, css, fonts, tags, font-size

I want to set `<Font size="+0">` in a lot of places so I want to set it in the CSS. Is that possible?

I tried `font-size: +0;` and that was a huge failure.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expected result is. Maybe `font-size:100%`?

Comment: I've found the answer just now. Hmmm... if the result is equal `font-size:medium;` then yeah

Comment: `font-size:medium`, and `font-size:1rem` are equivalent. `font-size:100%` and `font-size:1em` are almost equivalent, but are based on the parent's size instead of being absolute. Use the former if you want to use the default font-size, use the later if you want to leave the font-size unchanged.

Comment: The syntax you show is from HTML 3.2, which is an HTML flavour used 20 years ago... (the `<font>` element was deprecated in HTML4, which is from 1998). Can you explain what do you expect it to *do*, so that we can explain how to do that thing in modern CSS?

Comment: Yup, I want to do it from CSS side instead of using a tag

Comment: @SeanLeBlanc Font sizes `medium` and `1rem` are not always equivalent. The size of the rem can be changed in the stylesheet, the side of `medium` can not - it is fixed to the user's font settings in the browser preferences. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/p68h4Lvv/2/), where `1rem` is made equal to 30px, but `medium` is still equal to (usually) 16px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the answer! It's:

```
font-size: medium;
```

I found it based on a few links and a little bit of trial and error:

[HTML Style tag equivalent of "font size+2"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458157/html-style-tag-equivalent-of-font-size2#answer-9458187)

> `<font size="+2">` is equivalent to `font-size: x-large;`

Then I look for possible equivalent for `<font size="+0">`

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-size.asp